# Whether the function $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

> **QUESTION**:
>
> $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}x \sin \frac{1}{y} + y \sin \frac{1}{x} &
>  \text{if } xy \not = 0 \\ 0 & \text{if } xy = 0\end{cases}$$
>
> Show that $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

**MY ATTEMPT:**

What I have to do is:

1. Show that $f_x$ and $f_y$ both exist at $(0,0)$ and
2. Show that either of $f_x$ or $f_y$ is bounded .

Now, first of all, we have that
$$f_x(0,0)=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=0$$ and
$$f_y(0,0)=\lim_{k\to0} \frac{f(0,k)-f(0,0)}{k}=0$$

So the condition$(1)$ is satisfied.

For $(2)$, we have that
$$f_x=\sin \frac{1}{y} - \frac{y}{x^2} \cos \frac{1}{x}$$ and 
$$f_y=\sin \frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{y^2} \cos \frac{1}{y}$$

But then how do I show that $f_x$ or $f_y$ is bounded?

If possible, can you suggest some other method of proof by $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity?

Please help.

Comment: Try bounding $\left|x \sin \left(\frac{1}{y}\right) + y \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \right|$ by something that clearly goes to $0$.

Comment: The goal is to show continuity, not differentiability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not directly show the limit is zero?

$$\left|x\sin\frac1y+y\sin\frac1x\right|\le |x|+|y|\xrightarrow[(x,y)\to(0,0)]{}0$$

and we've finished since $\;f(0,0)=0\;$ .

Comment: You're too quick.  +1

Comment: lol that's embarrassing...

Comment: @Dr.MV Jeje...not really, just happened to be around at the right time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For all sequence $(x_n,y_n)\to (0,0)$ we have $f(x_n,y_n)\to f(0,0)=0$ because both $|\sin\frac 1x|$ and $|\sin \frac 1y|$ being bounded by $1$ we have $$|f(x_n,y_n)|=|x_n\sin \frac 1y_n+y_n\sin\frac 1x_n|\le |x_n|+|y_n|\to 0$$ This proves $f$ is continuous at the point $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

A function f(x,y) is said to be continuous at point (a,b) if limit $\lim_{x\to a  ,y\to b} f(x,y) = f(a,b)$

Therefore $\lim_{x\to 0,y\to 0} x\sin \frac{1}{y} + y \sin \frac{1}{x} = 0$ by sandwich theorem, also this is equal to $f(0,0)$.

Hence as $\lim_{x\to 0,y\to 0} x\sin \frac{1}{y} + y \sin \frac{1}{x} = f(0,0)$ the function is continuous at $(0,0)$

[For more details visit here.](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/Limits.aspx)